# How do I initialize a webworker in NextJS 10?

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js, web-worker, worker

I have a Next 10 project where I am trying to use WebWorkers. The worker is being initialized like so:

```
window.RefreshTokenWorker = new Worker(new URL('../refreshToken.worker.js', import.meta.url))
```

I also have the Worker defined as

```
self.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
  console.info("ON MESSAGE: ", e)
  // some logic with e.data
})
```

Its also being called like this:

```
const worker = getWorker() // gets worker that is attached at the window level
worker.postMessage('start')
```

My `next.config.js` file is defined as

```
const nextConfig = {
  target: 'serverless',
  env: getBuildEnvVariables(),
  redirects,
  rewrites,
  images: {
    domains: []
  },
  future: { webpack5: true },
  webpack (config) {
    config.resolve.alias['@'] = path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    return config
  }
}

// more definitions

module.exports = nextConfig
```

The issue I have is the `console.info` in the Web Worker definition does not receive the message being sent from `postMessage` on the build version (`yarn build && yarn start`) but it does on the dev version (`yarn dev`). Any ways to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

This is not a solution. But can be a messy way to do the job. This turned out to be a nightmare for me.

I have the same setup as yours. I was initializing web worker as you have shown in your question. I got this idea from the nextjs doc itself:  https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5

```
const newWebWorker = new Worker(new URL('../worker.js', import.meta.url))
```

Everything working correctly when I work in `dev` mode. it is picking up the `worker.js` file correctly and everything looks alright.

But when I build the nextjs and try it, then web worker won't work. When I dive deeply into the issues, I found out that the worker.js chunk file is created directly under the `.next` folder. It should come under `.next/static/chunk/[hash].worker.js` ideally.

I could not resolve this issue in a proper way.

So what i did, i placed my `worker.js` file directly under `public` directory. I put my `worker.js` file transpiled and optimized and put the code in the `public/worker.js` file.

After this, I modified the worker initialization like this:

```
const newWebWorker = new Worker('/worker.js', { type: 'module' });
```

it is working in the production build now. I will report once I get a cleaner solution for this.

Comment: Hi, this will not work in `dev` mode. Were you able to find a better solution?

Comment: @ShreyKumar it worked in `dev` mode for me. not sure why yours not working

Comment: @ShreyKumar did you find another way around this?

Answer (score 1):

I found something usefull

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5

it says something like

Support for web workers using new Worker(new URL("worker.js", import.meta.url))

and it worked for me just keep in mind, that you have to write it exactly how is written, mine looks something like this

```typescript
const worker = new Worker(new URL("./Player/Worker.ts", import.meta.url ), { type: 'module' })
```