# web worker not loading properly when using typescript on nextjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, next.js, webpack-5

I'm using next js for my project and it uses Webpack 5 for bundling.
according to this [webworkers](https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers/) I can use the following syntax to load my web workers:

```js
new Worker(new URL('./worker.js', import.meta.url));
```

but when I use the following:

```js
new Worker(new URL('./worker.ts', import.meta.url));
```

it is loading as a media type file on the browser and not resolving imports and exports for typescript. any suggestions as to how I can resolve this issue on next js?

my tsconfig:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", ".next", "out"],
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "global.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "**/*.mdx",
    "**/*.js",
    "workers/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67318031/10873797 might help guide you

Comment: Why are you even using worker.ts? Typescript is supposed to be compiled to js. And, the browser doesn't understand ts, as far as I know. Lastly, ts being shown as a media type file is reasonable because it is used in media stream file type.

Comment: @sno2 this answer uses javascript, my problem does not occur javascript it works fine, but when using typescript it doesn't transpile to javascript. the browser requests for [hash].worker.ts and detects it as media

Comment: @Shirshak55 I am aware that browser does not understand ts files. I'm trying to transpile it to javascript. and the reason that I'm using typescript is that I want to use types and libraries inside my project

Comment: @ArshiaMoghaddam I don't have any issue whether you use typescript or javascript. But Brower will use .ts instead of .js. I think you should use .js always in such cases? In the end, .ts file will be converted to .js anyway?

Comment: @Shirshak55 it doesn't convert, that's the problem. I'm trying to make a custom rule for webpack to convert it

Comment: @ArshiaMoghaddam Can you paste your tsconfig json?

Comment: @Shirshak55 of course I will update my question

Comment: The question is why doesn't it transpile my worker to JavaScript, not why can't the browser load and execute a web worker in a TypeScript file?

Comment: @kellys yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this exactly answers your question, but here is an option I've used for a Typescript only web worker experience. I think it is pretty neat and enables a nice object based coding model, so perhaps it meets your requirements?

**DEPENDENCIES**

Run these commands:

```sh
npm install comlink --save
npm install worker-loader --save-dev
```

**DEFINE THE WEB WORKER**

Add this to a `typings.d.ts` file:

```js
declare module 'worker-loader!*' {

    class WebpackWorker extends Worker {
        constructor();
    }

    export default WebpackWorker;
}
```

**CREATE THE WEB WORKER**

```js
import {expose} from 'comlink';

export class MyWebWorker {

  private readonly name: string;

  public constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }  

  public async getData(input: string) : Promise<any> {
    return {
      message: `Hello from web worker, ${name}, ${input}`;
    };
 }
}

expose(MyWebWorker);
```

**USE THE WEB WORKER**

```js
import {wrap, Remote} from 'comlink';
import Worker from 'worker-loader!./mywebworker';
import {MyWebWorker} from './mywebworker';

export class MyConsumingClass {

  public async callWebWorker(): Promise<void> {
  {
    const RemoteChannel = wrap<typeof MyWebWorker>(new Worker());
    const webWorker: Remote<MyWebWorker> = await new RemoteChannel("some name");
    const data = await webWorker.getData("some input");
    console.log(data.message);
  }
}
```

**WEBPACK BEHAVIOUR**

The above typings.d.ts file and worker-loader plugin means webpack 5 will output a file called `mywebworker.bundle.worker.js`, and note that this is lower cased. No reference to worker-loader is needed in the actual webpack file, though in my setup I used this output format, which may influence the name of the web worker bundle:

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
}
```

Comment: the `worker-loader` works for my problem, and I am frustrated. because it says it's depricated for webpack 5 and when you look into their code on github there is support for webpack 5. why is that? when I read that it's depricated I didn't look further into it